# there is one html tag inside the other

Tags: html

I'm new to this forum and in overall programing. recently I was searching for some info on .bat files and I came up with this microsoft page. I wanted to see if the code would reveal how old it was (because it does look old) and instead I found something that I find strange:
there was an html tag inside another html tag.

[the html tags are highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmixQ.jpg)

what does this do/mean?

thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: thats because thats in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Frames
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm

Basically, you can load a html file inside a frame. That's why you see 2 html tags.

Answer (score 0):

That's `<iframe>`. It's a tag which allows you to include other website on your website by using this tag.
You can read more about that here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

Give this a good read.

Tldr; dom encapsulation, create templates for js access without rendering the content, some other cool stuff

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/